# How to convert a Matrix4<f32> into a [f32; 16] using nalgebra

Tags: rust, nalgebra

I have a `Matrix4<f32>` representing a transformation. I would like to convert it to a `[f32; 16]` to use with [wgpu](https://docs.rs/wgpu_glyph/0.18.0/wgpu_glyph/struct.GlyphBrush.html#method.draw_queued_with_transform).

I've not managed to find the right method (if there is one at all).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `as_slice()` to convert it into a `&[f32]`, and then convert that into a `[f32; 16]` using `try_into()`.

Here's an example:

```rs
fn matrix_to_array(m: Matrix4<f32>) -> [f32; 16] {
    m.as_slice().try_into().unwrap()
}
```